# how can i exclude entire rows based on one observation in my r dataframe?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe of countries that have received certain scores (polity2) for each year up to 2018. I wish to remove any countries from the dataframe that have not scored a 6 or higher **continuously** from 1998 to 2018. I have been able to create a subset including only countries that have scored 6+ in the 1998-2018 period through this code:

```
    polity4 <- polity4[,c("scode", "country", "year",
                          "democ", "autoc", "polity2")]

    #storing subset of countries that fit the criteria of having Polity2 scores of 6 or above from 1998 to 2018

    democratic <- subset(polity4, (year>1997 & polity2 >= 6))
```

Here is the what the dataframe now looks like:

```
 scode country        year democ autoc polity2
   <chr> <chr>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 USA   United States  1998    10     0      10
 2 USA   United States  1999    10     0      10
 3 USA   United States  2000    10     0      10
 4 USA   United States  2001    10     0      10
 5 USA   United States  2002    10     0      10
 6 USA   United States  2003    10     0      10
 7 USA   United States  2004    10     0      10
 8 USA   United States  2005    10     0      10
 9 USA   United States  2006    10     0      10
10 USA   United States  2007    10     0      10
```

However I now wish to create a way of looping through the subset and removing rows that appear because the country has scored they have scored a 6+ **at least once** during the period, but not continuously over the 20 years.

I have tried creating a new column that counts the instances where a country appears in the new subset (it should be less than 21 for it to be continuous) in order to use this in the loop:

```
democratic$count <- democratic[,c("scode")] %>% group_by(scode) %>% mutate(count = n())
```

However I have experimented with using by() but can't figure out how to create this loop.

Sorry if I've made this overly complicated or if this is a stupid question, and thanks in advance.

EDIT: here is a section of the current dataframe:

```
scode country  year democ autoc polity2
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 RUM   Romania  1998     8     0       8
 2 RUM   Romania  1999     8     0       8
 3 RUM   Romania  2000     8     0       8
 4 RUM   Romania  2001     8     0       8
 5 RUM   Romania  2002     8     0       8
 6 RUM   Romania  2003     8     0       8
 7 RUM   Romania  2004     9     0       9
 8 RUM   Romania  2005     9     0       9
 9 RUM   Romania  2006     9     0       9
10 RUM   Romania  2007     9     0       9
11 RUM   Romania  2008     9     0       9
12 RUM   Romania  2009     9     0       9
13 RUM   Romania  2010     9     0       9
14 RUM   Romania  2011     9     0       9
15 RUM   Romania  2012     9     0       9
16 RUM   Romania  2013     9     0       9
17 RUM   Romania  2014     9     0       9
18 RUM   Romania  2015     9     0       9
19 RUM   Romania  2016     9     0       9
20 RUM   Romania  2017     9     0       9
21 RUM   Romania  2018     9     0       9
22 RUS   Russia   2000     6     0       6
23 RUS   Russia   2001     6     0       6
24 RUS   Russia   2002     6     0       6
25 RUS   Russia   2003     6     0       6
26 RUS   Russia   2004     6     0       6
27 RUS   Russia   2005     6     0       6
28 RUS   Russia   2006     6     0       6
29 EST   Estonia  1998     7     1       6
30 EST   Estonia  1999     8     1       7
```

Whereas Romania is fine as it has scored 6+ continuously from 1998 to 2018, Russia has only scored 6+ in 2000-06 and so does not fit the continuous criteria I am looking to implement and should be removed.

Comment: Could you please place a section of your dataframe in the question see [mre] for guidance or use `dput()`. This will allow us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `complete` the missing observations of `years` for each `country` and select only those countries where `all` values in `polity2` is greater than equal to 6.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 tidyr::complete(country, year, fill = list(polity2 = 0)) %>% 
 filter(year %in% 1998:2018) %>%
 group_by(country) %>%
 filter(all(polity2 >= 6))

#   country year scode democ autoc polity2
#1  Romania 1998   RUM     8     0       8
#2  Romania 1999   RUM     8     0       8
#3  Romania 2000   RUM     8     0       8
#4  Romania 2001   RUM     8     0       8
#5  Romania 2002   RUM     8     0       8
#6  Romania 2003   RUM     8     0       8
#7  Romania 2004   RUM     9     0       9
#8  Romania 2005   RUM     9     0       9
#9  Romania 2006   RUM     9     0       9
#10 Romania 2007   RUM     9     0       9
#11 Romania 2008   RUM     9     0       9
#12 Romania 2009   RUM     9     0       9
#13 Romania 2010   RUM     9     0       9
#14 Romania 2011   RUM     9     0       9
#15 Romania 2012   RUM     9     0       9
#16 Romania 2013   RUM     9     0       9
#17 Romania 2014   RUM     9     0       9
#18 Romania 2015   RUM     9     0       9
#19 Romania 2016   RUM     9     0       9
#20 Romania 2017   RUM     9     0       9
#21 Romania 2018   RUM     9     0       9
```

Comment: Thank you, if I use the above for the section of the dataframe that I have posted in my question (democratic[1019:1049,]), this works well. However, when I have tried to apply this method to the entire dataframe, it has returned 0 observations...

Comment: @HarryW Maybe there are other years present in the data so we have to filter first. Can you check the updated answer.